# Giving myself permissions in /etc/sudoers does nothing

Tags: command-line, permission, sudo

I want to give myself permissions to use `pmset` without using `sudo`.

I added this line to `etc/sudoers`:

```
myname          ALL = /usr/bin/pmset
```

But when I save and close with `:wq` and run `pmset`, I get:

```
$ pmset -b disablesleep 1
'pmset' must be run as root...
```

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sudoers` file only gets read by `sudo` so you still need to run

```
sudo pmset ...
```

to execute the command. What your addition to `sudoers` does is that every user on your Mac can now execute `pmset` without entering a password (or even be in the admin group).

If you want to avoid having to type `sudo pmset` each time define an alias

```
alias pmset="sudo /usr/bin/pmset"
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of parameters in sudoers is like [this](https://serversforhackers.com/c/sudo-and-sudoers-configuration):

> - **root** ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL - This applies to user root
> - root **ALL**=(ALL:ALL) ALL - This rule applies to all user root logged in from all hosts
> - root ALL=(**ALL**:ALL) ALL - User root can run commands as all users
> - root ALL=(ALL:**ALL**) ALL - User root can run commands as all groups
> - root ALL=(ALL:ALL) **ALL** - These rules apply to all commands

Your addition `myname ALL = /usr/bin/pmset` to sudoers contains the first, second and fifth parameters and therefore means user `myname` on any host can run `sudo pmset`.  If they were a member of the `%admin` group (as the first user created on macOS is) they would have been able to do this anyway.

What is doesn't do is tell sudo is that you don't want to enter a password which is done with the [NOPASSWD](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) parameter.  Therefore you want, as the last line in sudoers for `myname`:

```
myname          ALL = NOPASSWD : /usr/bin/pmset
```

This will let user `myname` enter `sudo pmset` without prompting for a password. If you wish you can then make an alias as described in the [other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/385071/115093) and add it to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`